# Where can you download Managed JScript for the DLR?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, dynamic-language-runtime, managed-jscript

The lastest release (0.9 Stable) of the Dynamic Language Runtime contains IronPython and IronRuby, but it doesn't contain Managed JScript.

Does anyone know where I can download the latest release of Managed JScript for use with ASP.NET and/or WPF?

In case you aren't aware, JScript.NET and Managed JScript are too different things. What I'm looking for is Managed JScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update...

The Silverlight Dynamic Language SDK 0.5.0 [Release Notes](http://sdlsdk.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25120) posted March 23rd, 2009 on [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com), contained this little gem:

> Managed JScript has been removed from
>   the package.

When asked in [this thread](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58121) about the future of Managed JScript (IronJScript), Bill ([billchi](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/billchi)), a coordinator on the [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://dlr.codeplex.com) forum, had the following to say:

> The DLR JScript was experimental for
>   informing the design of the DLR
>   (expression trees, interop, callsites,
>   hosting, etc.).  The JS we released
>   with asp futures and the Silverlight
>   dynamic sdk became very old and
>   unserviceable as the DLR continued
>   evolving for release in CLR 4.0. 
>   Unfortunately, there are no plans at
>   this time to develop and release a
>   DLR-hostable JScript.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Bill

(edit to add quote from a later post)

> The JScript team will continue
>   supporting using native Jscript
>   (jscript.dll) with IActiveScript. 
>   They’ll also continue to service
>   Jscript.NET, but they aren’t making
>   other commitments at this point.
>
> Bill

Considering the JScript.NET scripting API's are now all obsolete (though they are still present in .NET 2.0), there therefore appears to be no .NET upgrade path off of the ActiveScripting implementation of JScript (JavaScript).

May I suggest that discussion (protest ;-) be directed to [that thread](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58121).

Comment: Note that the main issue blocking our commercial use of JScript.NET is that there does not appear to be (a documented) method of initializing the script's global scope and retaining scope when calling into functions and methods - the globals appear to be left unintialized.  Going to post a question here about doing just that.

Comment: See question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937351/can-jscript-net-be-used-to-script-a-net-application

Comment: Oh that totally blows. So it's going to be supported in Silverlight only? Is that the gist of this?

Comment: That's amazing. That kills all kinds of porting possibilities between platforms.

Comment: Nope, gone - that should have read "removed from the *Silverlight* DLR SDK". Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Never fear, Fredrik Holmström is working on [IronJS](http://github.com/fholm/IronJS), an implementation of JavaScript on the DLR in F#. He's currently targeting .NET 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0, as well as Mono 2.6, but would eventually like to get to Silverlight integration when the library becomes more stable.

Comment: IronJS has come a long way! Way to go Fredrik!!

Answer (score 1):

Rumor this week out of the Redmond "Metro" DotNet futures conference is that MSFT decided to kill ManagedJScript on the DLR.

That's the reason we aren't hearing anything about it.

Comment: That really sucks! It sure would be nice to use JavaScript/JScript for all desktop and web development.

Answer (score 1):

download Managed JS:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a5189bcb-ef81-4c12-9733-e294d13a58e6&displaylang=en

Comment: You do realize this link is to a 3 year old CTP release, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/gauravseth/archive/2007/08/16/difference-between-jscript-jscript-net-and-managed-jscript.aspx), Managed JScript is delivered as part of Silverlight 2 (1.1). To write applications you'll want the [Dynamic Language SDK](http://silverlight.net/learn/dynamiclanguages.aspx).

**edit:** For ASP.NET, it is available in the [ASP.NET Futures](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5189BCB-EF81-4C12-9733-E294D13A58E6&displaylang=en) but that has been "retired" according to [this entry](http://forums.asp.net/t/1353527.aspx) and isn't currently available in another official release.

Comment: Yes that would work if I were looking to use it in Silverlight, but I'm looking to use Managed JScript with ASP.NET and possibly even WPF.

Comment: I should have been more clear about the releases. I've added a clarification to the answer.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to try getting the Silverlight version to work with ASP.NET and/or WPF. It sucks they've discontinued it. I've wanted to write "real" applications using JavaScript for a long time to see how the experience could be using the language in that way. Now I just need to find the time to play with this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer, but obsolete (hence the downvote). See later posts in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the ASP.NET Futures

Comment: Where can it be downloaded? The link doesn't seem to be on www.asp.net anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Managed JScript been really hard to find relative to IronPython or IronRuby. Pretty much the only place to find it is the ASP.Net futures. But that's two years old now and not supported. ECMAScript 5 is getting standardized right now and should be done some time in 2009. Maybe Microsoft is waiting until the new standard is out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen ROScript? http://www.remobjects.com/script.aspx
Supposed to support both ECMAScirpt and PascalScript