# Parse Formulae in .NET

Tags: c#, parsing, formula

I am trying to parse formula in C# language like

```
"5*3 + 2" 
"(3*4 - 2)/5"
```

Is it possible to do in C# or scripts like VBScript, JavaScript (which will be called in c# program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick I've used before to do this sort of thing in C#, which is to use JScript.NET's `eval` function. You'll find the complete code in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896503/what-are-people-using-jscript-net-for). It's not relying on a scripting language like VBScript or JavaScript, it's pure .NET, and the implementation I use generates a JScript.NET assembly on the fly from C# code, so there's no need to mix languages in your solution.

Comment: Thanks David, this is what I want.

Answer (score 4):

I've had great experience with [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/), a C# library that evaluates expressions such as the one you've described.  You can evaluate the expressions as strongly typed statements, so if you wanted an integer for example, "(1 + 2) * 5" would be okay but "hello world" would not.

You can even hook in specific variables or functions.  The [Flee examples page](http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) is a great starting point.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But flee needs to be downloaded, hence I preferred JScript.Net.

Comment: It's in fact a VB.NET library. I got freaked out when I took a look at the source to try to understand some issues I was having!

Comment: +1 to Flee - I evaluated over 50K expressions in 4 mins. Expressions were not complex, only arithmetic, and few null checks

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) sample from Microsoft to dynamically formulate expressions which use types under the [System.Linq.Expressions namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx). This works very well for me and allows me to use a more natural C# syntax in place of [ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx) default expressions.