# Is there an easy way to embed a Javascript interpreter in a C# application?

Tags: c#, javascript

Is there an easy way to embed Javascript in a C# application?

I want to make my C# application scriptable.

I have used Lua for this in the past but would like to use Javascript in this instance.  LuaInterface is a nice C# wrapper for the C Lua API and it made it really easy to embed Lua  in C# and a lot less painful than writing a Managed C++ wrapper for the Lua API (I have tried that as well).

Are there any C# libraries around for embedding Javascript that are as easy to use as LuaInterface?

Comment: I've added a link to something that looks similar. But I wonder whether IronPython would be another option?

Comment: Thanks, IronPython sounds interesting.  This question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There is one: Jint (http://jint.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider working with the DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime).

Managed JScript is built on the top of DLR (can't insert second link as I'm a new user):

http://blogs.msdn.com/deepak/archive/2007/05/02/managed-jscript-is-availaible.aspx

Comment: Managed JScript would be great, but it sounds like it is no longer available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775339/where-can-you-download-managed-jscript-for-the-dlr